# What is the range of a Force Teleport?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends

What is exactly the maximum range of the teleportation ability?

I did not find any mention of how far someone can teleport in the [wiki](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Teleport). Mother Talzin in *The Clone Wars* S04E19 managed to teleport far away from Grievous to where Asajj Ventress was. So, it proves that it's possible to teleport long distances. But is it possible to teleport from one planet to another?

Comment: The wiki repeatedly mentions a likely maximum range; eyeball distance

Comment: I expect it depends on the will of the Plot ... uh, Force.  Will of the Force.

Comment: Is Mother Talzin using the force?

Comment: No idea, but you definitely can’t ever do it while travelling at warp speed.

Comment: yes Mother talzin definitely uses force, to be exact the nightsisters use dark side of the force.They just call it magic.

Answer (score 2):

Mother Talzin and other Nightsisters use something called [Magick](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Magick), a mysterious aspect of the Force. Some claim that it comes from Dark Side, some that it is a gift from [Winged Goddess](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Daughter), some that source of its power came from [ichor](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Magical_ichor) in the depths of Dathomir.

Powerful witches like Talzin have the ability to transfer to something called the "spirit world", with their body disappearing from the physical realm. With some effort, Talzin could also recreate her body as witnessed in her final fight against Sidious. What exactly this spirit world is and how did it operates is presently unknown to us, and likely never to be fully reviled because Disney decided not to pursue the Dathomirian plot anymore - the Nightsister cult is effectively destroyed and they have been for all practical purposes removed from further stories.

As for other users of teleport ability, they belong to Legends, with even less rules. Most notable examples are of course from the game [Star Wars: The Old Republic](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Old_Republic), where this power limited itself to local transfers of either user himself or someone whom he wished to move. Unlike Mother Talzin, they could not use Force Teleport to travel long distances.

Comment: What about Fold Space Technique? Are there any hint of this techniques range in Extended universe?

Comment: @JohannAlexisFaust Who knows. Abeloth was almost like deity in Legends, she had physical avatars but her true presence was in the Force . From what I know, she was not restricted by distance in her true form.